# a java excel api for addressing my requirements?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Problem description: i want to load image pixel data in excel sheet.

what i have tried: using apache POI for writing the data to excel, but i found there are some limitations in apache POI (as elaborated below)
I have come to know of some workarounds, which are tedious on the part of the programmer and i am not really willing to do that for such a trivial looking task.

Details:

i have been using apache POI for quite some time, and i have come across few limitations:

- the whole file is in memory at once, so cant use directly for bigger files.

(specific to HSSF) :

- no more than 255 columns
- no more than 4000 cell styles
- cant use custom colors directly.

my requirement is to read an image(say, 1024x764) pixel by pixel and write pixel value in rows and columns of the excel sheet, every different pixel value is styled differently.

the problems i have faced are:

- out of memory exception, while writing to the excel sheet, because of so many rows/columns and styles
- writing a logic for reusing styles would slow down the whole program
- even if i reuse styles, what to do about the huge number of rows/columns

I have come to know that there are workarounds for these problems:

- reusing styles
- writing logic for efficient memory usage

but i do not intend to take much pain for a job as simple as that, and since these are not directly the limitations of excel (atleast not .xlsx), i am looking for a library that can do it for me.

can someone please suggest another library which can do this,or can you suggest some easier workarounds for these problems?

Comment: i have edited the question and added relevant info at the top.
I dont believe this query **attracts opinionated answers and spam** as i have a valid,specific set of requirements which i am looking answers for, and looking for another library which may be able to do so without much load on the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

> can someone please suggest a good library to do this, or else i would change from java to csharp

In short, nope - the POI libraries are, in my experience, the best ones available for the job. They're not perfect, but I don't know of an alternative that's better. You may want to try [checking trunk out](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/) and seeing if any of your issues have been resolved there - entirely possible, it's a relatively active project.

The only other thing I'd suggest looking at is the [OpenOffice API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/), but note that requires OO to be installed (or distributed with your app.)

In all honesty though, POI's strength is it's cross platform nature - it's a pure Java implementation with no native components. If you don't care about this and could therefore go with C# and use the native office APIs, this would seem like the logical approach surely? It seems odd to me that you're not doing this already.

Comment: i am not doing this already because i am looking for a java solution.
c# would have to be my last resort.i am hoping that there is an easier way in java to do this trivial looking task (copying image pixel data to excel)

Answer (score 0):

JExcelApi
http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

It works in declarative mode, as Adobe LifeCycle e JReport: you create a Template file xls andin every cell you put the reference to the beans.

Invoking the engine, a the end you have a XLS file.

Sorry for the extreme synthesis, but I worked with it a lot of years ago and I don't remember the details, but in the website  there's the documentation.

Comment: Entirely true, but OP explicitely needs XLSX support, which is a feature that's sorely missing in jExcelAPI

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that jExcelAPI (when I used it at least) still held the entire file in memory at once?